# Showing or refuting that topologist's sine curve is simply connected.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $S^{-}=\left\{0\right\}\times [-1,1]$ and $S^{+}= \left\{(x,\sin(1/x):x\in ]0,1]\right\}$  and $S=S^{-}\cup S^{+}$ (topologist's sine curve)

Hi. I would like to know if the following statement that seem intuitive to me are correct (and then try to proves them rigorously)

It is known that $S$ is connected but not path connected but: $S^{-}$ and $S^{+}$ are simply connected? i.e  $S^{\pm }$ is path connected and for any $x_0\in S^{\pm}$, $\pi_{1}(S^{\pm},x_0)=\left\{[e_{x_0}]\right\}$ ($e_{x_0}$ is trivial loop in $x_0$)

Answer (score 3):

**Visualization**: Both $S^-$ and $S^+$  are contractible. It is easy to show that $S^-$ contracts to the point $(0,0)$. And note that $S^-$ is homeomorphic to the the open-closed interval $(0,1]$ as you can stretched and straighten the curve $S^+:=\big\{\big(x,\sin\frac{1}{x}\big) :0<x\leq 1\big\}$ to make it a line segment.

**Proof:** Note that $S^-$ is homeomorphic to $[-1,1]$ and $H_t:[-1,1]\ni x\longmapsto (1-t)x\in [-1,1]$ for all $0\leq t\leq 1$ defines a contraction of $[-1,1]$ to $0\in [-1,1]$.

Next note that $S^+$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1]$ via projection on the first component i.e. $S^+\ni \big(x,\sin\frac{1}{x}\big)\longmapsto x\in (0,1]$. Now, $(0,1]$ is a contactible, so we are done.

Comment: I get it. So all the fundamental group in the topologist'sine curve are isomorphic and they are all trivial.

Comment: The fundamental groups of $S^+$ and $S^-$ are trivial.

Comment: $\pi_1(S)$ is not trivial?

Comment: Note that $S$ is not path-connected, and it has exactly two path-component, $S^-$ and $S^+$. So, you can't say $\pi_1(S)$, rather you have to specify a point, i.e. either you have to consider $\pi_1(S,x_0)$ where $x_0\in S^-$ and in this case $\pi_1(S,x_0)=\pi_1(S^-,x_0)=0$ or you have to consider $\pi_1(S,y_0)$ where $y_0\in S^+$ and in this case $\pi_1(S,y_0)=\pi_1(S^+,y_0)=0$.

Comment: Why it is so? Note that fundamental group is a collection of equivalence classes of all loop based at some fixed point $x$. In other words, all loops based at $x$ lie in same path-component, and this path-component is nothing but the path-component containing $x$. Note that we are using the fact that continuous image of a path-connected set is path-connected. That's all.

Comment: I see. in general, if $X'\subset X$, $X'$ a path connected component of $X$ and $x_0\in X'$ then $\pi_1(X,x_0)=\pi_1(X',x_0)$? (This would be the argument that has been used apparently)

Comment: Yeah, if $X'$ is the path-component of $X$ containing $x_0$.

Comment: and how is it possible to prove that? I stagnate in a step.
Let $[f]\in \pi_1(X,x_0)$ with $x_0\in X'$ then $f:[0,1]\to X$ continuous and $f(0)=f(1)=x_0\in X'$
I need proves that $f(x)\in X'$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ but I have only $X'$ path connected component of $X$.

Comment: The continuous image of a path-connected set is path-connected and every path-connected set is contained in a **unique** path component.